# Authenticating Databasedotcom Gem

Tags: ruby

I am attempting to connect and authenticate a rails app with the [databasedotcom gem](https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom)

I am following the tutorial [here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Accessing_Salesforce_Data_From_Ruby). *But he doesn't mention some of the other considerations that your request must come from an SSL enabled environment*!

So I've modified my Ruby/Webrick configuration to allow for a self-signed CSR I generated as follows.

I am only mentioning this because: *I don't know if it's an issue with how I'm authenticating or the SSL configuration of webrick*! I get the following exception when I attempt to authenticate the client in the *rails console* or in the running *webapp*.

The app runs fine in SSL w/o initializing the client and attempting to authenticate, so I think that's where my issue is but I'm not sure?

```
$ client = Databasedotcom::Client.new("config/databasedotcom.yml")
$ client.authenticate :username => 'login@domain.com',:password => 'mypassword_authtoken'
    TypeError: can't convert Pathname into String
from /Users/jordanbaucke/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:658:in `init
ialize'
from /Users/jordanbaucke/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:658:in `new'
from /Users/jordanbaucke/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:658:in `conn
ect'
from /Users/jordanbaucke/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_s
tart'
from /Users/jordanbaucke/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `star
t'
from /Users/jordanbaucke/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1168:in `req
uest'
from /Users/jordanbaucke/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:978:in `post
'
from /Users/jordanbaucke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/databasedotcom-1.3.2/lib/databasedot
com/client.rb:110:in `authenticate'
from (irb):2
from /Users/jordanbaucke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/c
onsole.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/jordanbaucke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/c
onsole.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/jordanbaucke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties 3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.r
b:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:35:in `require'
from script/rails:35:in `<main>'
```

**config/databasedotcom.yml**

```
host: login.salesforce.com        # Use test.salesforce.com for sandbox
client_secret: ***         # This is the Consumer Secret from Salesforce
client_id: ***    # This is the Consumer Key from Salesforce
sobject_module: SFDC_Models       # See below for details on using modules
debugging: true                   # Can be useful while developing
username: ***
password: ***
```

And here are my modifications to get Webrick running SSL:

**script/rails**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rails/commands/server'
require 'rack'
require 'webrick'
require 'webrick/https'
module Rails
    class Server < ::Rack::Server
        def default_options
            super.merge({
                :Port => 3000,
                :environment => (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "development").dup,
                :daemonize => false,
                :debugger => false,
                :pid => File.expand_path("tmp/pids/server.pid"),
                :config => File.expand_path("config.ru"),
                :SSLEnable => true,
                :SSLVerifyClient => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
                :SSLPrivateKey => OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(
                       File.open("server.key").read),
                :SSLCertificate => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(
                       File.open("server.csr").read),
                :SSLCertName => [["CN", WEBrick::Utils::getservername]]
            })
        end
    end
end
```

**config/initializers/fix_ssl.rb**

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'net/https'

module Net
  class HTTP
    alias_method :original_use_ssl=, :use_ssl=

    def use_ssl=(flag)
      self.ca_file = Rails.root.join('server.crt')
      self.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
      self.original_use_ssl = flag
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jordan,

I know that this is sort of a side step to the original question, but I do think it's a quick-win, so here we go.

Ruby ships with WebBrick, and as you've learned it doesn't support HTTPS natively. Well, not at least without some hacking. The Ruby Community has several other local http servers for local (and production) use. One of the turnkey replacements is called Thin. Your project directory likely has a file named Gemfile, and if it does you can install thin by adding the line:

> `gem 'thin'`

Saving, and running the command

> `bundle install`

This will install thin for your project and set you up.

However, instead of running rails s, or padrino start or ruby ./path/to/sinatraFile.rb You'll have to start up thin in https mode.

My preferred way of doing this is to use this bit of voodoo:

> `tail -f /path/to/relevant/logFile && thin start --ssl -p3000`

This will start tailing the log file, as if you had issued a rails s command, and start up thin in ssl mode on port 3000. Note you'll have to edit your browser url strings to be https://

Alternatively, there's a growing number of Ruby users who utilize the Foreman gem, in conjunction with Thin, to "mock out" a complete production environment. In principle this is fantastic! but the implementation can be a bit voodoo (violates the rule of least surprise, **imho**). If you'd like to use foreman, you can put the following two lines in your `procfile`

> `web: thin start`
>
> `ssl: thin start --ssl`

once thats done, you'll be able to startup your app locally with

> `foreman start`

Keep checking back here, I'm going to post a link to a github project stubbed out and ready for your credentials as a  "base project" for interacting with sf.com via ruby.

Comment: thanks Kevin! I will try switching to 'thin' and attempt to boot SSL that way

Comment: Jordan: As promised, here's a fully working demo: https://github.com/noeticpenguin/databasedotcom-demo

Comment: Awesome! I'm all over it after work today...gonna use this in my demo next month

Answer (score 1):

This is also a non-answer

I tried running the code you have above and it works fine for me from an IRB console so I think the SSL/Webrick thing is a red herring -- that's only necessary if you're doing the OAuth dance since the callback URL must be an SSL url (with the special case exception of localhost URLs) when setting up the Remote Access profile

We started with the databasedotcom gem but phased it out in deference to the restforce gem. The databasedotcom gem didn't let us do aggregate queries and the fact that it materializes an SObject into a Ruby object is sometimes problematic -- especially if you're logging into multiple organizations where the definition of the object changes

https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce

The databasedotcom gem has mostly atrophied as evidenced by this thread:

https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom/pull/105

Comment: Thanks for the advice daveespo - I'll have a look. Yeah it seems a lot less complicated to avoid SSL unless absolutely necessary.